# URL in NodeJS, collection path

Tags: node.js

I have question how can I download path with url after www.example.pl/~~

example: 
www.example.pl/user/create
-> /user/create

And second question is, is there function to find word in path ?
example:
www.example.pl/user/create
find(create)
answer: true

Thanks !

Comment: what do you mean by 'download path with url'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2nd one

```
const { URL } = require('url');
const myURL = new URL('https://example.org/abc/xyz?123');
 myURL.pathname.match('abc')
```

**[ 'abc', index: 1, input: '/abc/xyz' ]**

**> myURL.pathname.match('seww')
null**